# Necesito enviar datos a un DropwDownList y que tenga selecionado uno ya, en asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Este es mi código de la vista

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.nombreP, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.nombrep, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Este es mi codigo del Controlador

```
ViewBag.nombrep = new SelectList(list, "idProducto", "nombreProducto");
```

lo necesito para editar y que me salga el valor seleccionado de la fila que voy a editar en este caso el producto

Answer (score 0):

Si `model.nombreP` tiene valor entonces se mostrará selecionado el elemento de la lista que coincida con  ese valor. En el modelo asignale a `nombreP` el valor de `idProducto`  que está seleccionado.

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.nombreP, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.nombrep, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 0):

`SelectList` admite un cuarto parámetro que sería el objeto seleccionado, por tanto:

`var producto` `=`

> ... código para obtener un producto de la lista ...

;

```
ViewBag.nombrep = new SelectList(list, "idProducto", "nombreProducto", producto.idProducto );
```